# Why data duplicated when creating data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and now am trying to do web scraping using R. I got all the informations I need and want to combine them into a data frame. But when I compile the information, I found that my information all duplicated. Here is my code with the outputs:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
url<-'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Midnight-Black-256GB-Storage/dp/B077PWBC6V/ref=dp_prsubs_1?pd_rd_i=B077PWBC6V&psc=1'
webpage<- read_html(url)
title_html<- html_nodes(webpage,'h1#title')
title<-html_text(title_html)
head(title)
#> [1] "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nOnePlus 6 (Midnight Black, 8GB RAM, 256GB Storage)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
str_replace_all(title,"[\r\n]","")
#> [1] "OnePlus 6 (Midnight Black, 8GB RAM, 256GB Storage)"
price_html<-html_nodes(webpage,'span#priceblock_ourprice')
price<-html_text(price_html)
str_replace_all(price,"[\r\n]","")
#> [1] "\u20b9 43,999.00"
desc_html <- html_nodes(webpage, 'div#productDescription')
desc <- html_text(desc_html)
desc<-str_replace_all(desc,"[\r\n\t]","")
desc<-str_trim(desc)
head(desc)
#> [1] "Size name:256GB | Colour:blackThe OnePlus 6 comes with a 19:9 Full Optic AMOLED display, 20+16 MP dual primary camera, 6/8 GB of RAM; up to 256 GB memory, Snapdragon 845 processor and much more"
rate_html<-html_nodes(webpage,'span#acrPopover')
rate<-html_text(rate_html)
rate<- str_replace_all(rate,"[\r\n]","")
rate<- str_trim(rate)
head(rate)
#> [1] "4.6 out of 5 stars" "4.6 out of 5 stars"
size_html<- html_nodes(webpage,'div#variation_size_name')
size_html<-html_nodes(size_html, 'span.selection')
size<- html_text(size_html)
size<-str_trim(size)
head(size)
#> [1] "256GB"
color_html <- html_nodes(webpage, 'div#variation_color_name')
color_html <- html_nodes(color_html, 'span.selection')
color <- html_text(color_html)
color <- str_trim(color)
head(color)
#> [1] "black"
product_data <- data.frame(Title = title, Price = price,Description = desc, Rating = rate, Size = size, Color = color)
str(product_data)
#> 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  6 variables:
#>  $ Title      : chr  "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nOnePlus 6 (Midnight Black, 8GB RAM, 256GB Storage)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nOnePlus 6 (Midnight Black, 8GB RAM, 256GB Storage)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
#>  $ Price      : chr  "<U+20B9> 43,999.00" "<U+20B9> 43,999.00"
#>  $ Description: chr  "Size name:256GB | Colour:blackThe OnePlus 6 comes with a 19:9 Full Optic AMOLED display, 20+16 MP dual primary "| __truncated__ "Size name:256GB | Colour:blackThe OnePlus 6 comes with a 19:9 Full Optic AMOLED display, 20+16 MP dual primary "| __truncated__
#>  $ Rating     : chr  "4.6 out of 5 stars" "4.6 out of 5 stars"
#>  $ Size       : chr  "256GB" "256GB"
#>  $ Color      : chr  "black" "black"
```

Can anyone tell me what is my problem? And also why my title still have `\n\n` even though I have removed it? I am sorry that post all my code here because I am not sure where is my bug...Sorry and thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure about your other question - but the remaining newline characters `\n` are because you don't overwrite your title variable with the `str_replace_all` call, as in the line: `str_replace_all(title,"[\r\n]","")`, ie should be `title <- str_replace_all(title,"[\r\n]","")`

Comment: De-duplicate by changing `rate_html<-html_nodes(webpage,'span#acrPopover')` to `rate_html<-html_node(webpage,'span#acrPopover')`. In fact, if you only want a single match each time I'm guessing all calls should be `html_node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have duplicates is because the rate info has duplicate lines. I created a helper function for you so you don't have to repeat yourself (DRY principle). Here, I inserted a call to `unique()` to ensure you don't get out duplicates. As Gavin pointed out in the comment, you didn't reassign title, that's why the `\n`'s remained in your title. Let me know if the below helps.

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
url <- paste(
  'https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Midnight-Black-256GB-Storage/dp',
  '/B077PWBC6V/ref=dp_prsubs_1?pd_rd_i=B077PWBC6V&psc=1',
  sep = ''
)
webpage <- read_html(url)

parseInfo <- function(webpage, node) {
  info <- webpage %>% 
    html_nodes(node) %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    str_replace_all('[\r\n\t]', '') %>% 
    str_trim() %>% 
    unique()
  return(info)
}

title <- parseInfo(webpage, 'h1#title')
price <- parseInfo(webpage, 'span#priceblock_ourprice')
desc <- parseInfo(webpage, 'div#productDescription')
rate <- parseInfo(webpage, 'span#acrPopover')
size <- parseInfo(webpage, 'div#variation_size_name')
color <- parseInfo(webpage, 'div#variation_color_name')

product_data <- data.frame(
  Title = title,
  Price = price, 
  Description = desc,
  Rating = rate, 
  Size = size, 
  Color = color
)
```

Comment: Yeah it helps! Thank you! But I don't understand what does it mean by "the rate info has duplicate lines", can you explain a bit?

Comment: No problem. As an experiment, try changing the helper function to not make a call to `unique()`. If you run this for rate and inspect it, you will see rate is a vector of `"4.6 out of 5 stars", "4.6 out of 5 stars"`. This was the reason why the entire dataframe in your case had two identical rows. Calling `unique()` mitigated this.  
If the answer helps please don't hesitate to accept it.

Comment: I see, but why is that happen? The problem is from the webpage or the code? So because of the rate, the other information will duplicate as well?

Comment: Yes - since one input to the dataframe has twice the rows of the other inputs, the other inputs get duplicated too. I believe Hadley Wickham has written about this in [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/).

Comment: I can understand now. Thanks for your clear explanations!

Comment: Can you not use html_node?